# How can I fully remove Lutris?

Tags: games, software-uninstall, lutris

I wanted to fully uninstall lutris. What I did is run these commands:

```
sudo apt remove lutris
sudo apt autoremove
```

Sadly I found that there are 27 GB still in the directories (local , share, lutris, runners, wine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely expected and normal practice.
APT does not touch user files in home directory on package removal.

So you have to remove the Lutris associated directory inside home folder manually.

Comment: Oh , now I see that there is such  an option , thank you